# Session management in Java web applications

Tags: jsp, session

How do I manage my Session in web application? Ex: Suppose in my project I have 400 jsp pages which are all interlinked with each other and when I click on each link, that particular page have to load only if the session is active.If the session is inactive it have to redirect to the login.jsp page. I'm worried that whether I have to check the status of the session variable in each and every page before it load or is there any easy way to check?

Comment: little unsure... but as far as simple JSP servlet is concerned... I think this is the only way you can get it..

Answer (score 0):

There are some solution. For example you can add a servlet to web.xml that checks every request so you can control the session related logic in that servlet.

Comment: A filter would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any frameworks for your Java web application? Because a lot of them will maintain a session hash in the cookie, and will automatically check its validity on every client request (and redirect to a login flow if it's no longer valid).